# Paypal Sandbox Return Url not working vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, returnurl

I am in the beginning stages of working with paypal checkout in my website and I am trying to use a sandbox account to test some things out. I am able to go through and purchase the item with another sandbox account but after I purchase the item, it stays on the paypal checkout page and tells me that I have completed my payment and I will receive an email notification. I need it to return to some other website url so that I can try to get details of the transaction in my code behind. My code posted below is very basic and I do not have anything in the code itself about the return URL, I have filled it in under my sandbox account settings.

The second part of the problem is that I have not published my website yet, I am using the visual basic debugger to view and test my site in a browser and when I attempt to put my "local host" url into the return url it gives an error: "We were unable to validate the URL you have entered. Please check your entry and try again." an example of the url I am trying to put in is

```
http://localhost:11111/WebSite1/Parts_Catalog.aspx
```

As a test url just to attempt to start getting data back from the transaction I just put in google.com thinking that it would at least return to google with either an error or the returned query strings but it doesn't attempt to load any pages at all after the transaction.

How can I get the paypal sandbox return url to actually return to a URL? How can I enter my local host URL into the website preferences return url and actually get it to recognize my url as listed above?

Here is the markup code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server"
    RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
    ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png"
    OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" />
```

Here is the code I have so far for my addToCart button, I don't know if I need to add anything here or not for the return url

```
 Protected Sub AddToCartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
 Dim Item As String = "Test"
    Dim price As String = cost
    Dim business As String = "test@aol.com"
    Dim itemNumber As String = str2
    Dim itemAmount As String = price
    Dim currencyCode As String = "USD"
    Dim addItem As Integer = 1

    Dim ppHref As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    ppHref.Append("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart")
    ppHref.Append("&business=" + business)
    ppHref.Append("&item_name=" + itemName)
    ppHref.Append("&item_number=" + itemNumber)
    ppHref.Append("&amount=" + itemAmount)
    ppHref.Append("&currency_code=" + currencyCode)
    ppHref.Append("&add=" + addItem.ToString("#0"))
    Response.Redirect(ppHref.ToString(), True)
    Dim ReturnQaunity As String = itemAmount
    GetRouteUrl("/v1/payments/orders/<Order-Id>")
End Sub
```

I don't currently have anything in my page load event that deals with paypal.

Comment: You can't pass a localhost url... Or PayPal server will try to access his local host, which means itself

Comment: Ok do you know of any work arounds to this or as listed above, if I just use some other url like "google.com" will it still return to google.com with the transaction details appended in the url string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andre is right, the return URL must be accessible to PayPal.

What you can do is use a generic URL (I guess google.com would work but it might be better to use one of your own) then edit the URL in the browser window.

So return to something like `http://www.test.com/return.html?paypalparms...` 
Then when it displays in your browser change the URL to

```
http://localhost/return.html?paypalparms...
```

Then press enter.

I have used a similar technique with PayPal PDT and IPN testing and it works fine.

*I would have replied to your comment but I haven't yet reached the dizzy heights of 50 reputation which allows me to comment everywhere.*

Comment: Ok, the other problem I am having is that even if I have google.com as the return Url in my account settings for sandbox, It's not redirecting the page, it just sits on the paypal checkout confirmation page.

Comment: Do you have Auto Return on?

On my profile page for Website Payment Preferences it is just above where I enter the Return URL

Comment: Yes auto return is on and the return url is google.com for me right now. Strangely enough, this last time that I just tried it, it worked. The only problem is that the return url was https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl how do I get transaction details from this? and what is the 'gws_rd' stand for

Comment: I think that is Google doing that
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/5Toplm6lXPQ

Make sure you are using https for your google.com URL

But I wouldn't use google.com myself, it is too clever, I would use a website I knew wasn't going to do anything with my input.

Comment: nevermind, thats google switching over to their https site because I was redirecting to http://google.com.

Comment: Do I need to actually call query strings in the return url or what in order to get the transaction details? This is where I have been extremely confused as I try to look over info on this for the last 3 weeks. The biggest part of the data that I need is buyer name, item purchased, quantity, and price but I can't figure out how to retrieve this data

Comment: You need to look at Payment Data Transfer 

https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-intro-outside

That is the UK version, there are slightly different offerings in different markets.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a pretty good article on Payment Data Transfer for vb.net at https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_pdt.vb my only challenge right now is that I don't have any other live sites so it is going to be hard for me to test any of this out until I guess I take this site live that I'm working on. If you have any suggestions on a good way to test this on my localhost url it would be greatly appreciated, if not, Thank you very much for all your help. enjoy your 50+ reputation!